Netty server can't handle more than 1K TPS
I have a Netty Server defined as follows in the code.

private static final int BOSS_GROUP_THREAD_COUNT = 1;
private static final int WORKER_GROUP_THREAD_COUNT = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2;

private ChannelFuture bootStrapNettyServer(Context context) {
        ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap()
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 512)
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR, true)
                .childOption(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
                .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
                .childOption(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 5)
                .childOption(ChannelOption.ALLOCATOR, PooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT)
                .localAddress(config.getListenPort())
                .childHandler(new Initializer(context, createHandlers()));

        if (Epoll.isAvailable()) {
            bossGroup = new EpollEventLoopGroup(BOSS_GROUP_THREAD_COUNT);
            workerGroup = new EpollEventLoopGroup(WORKER_GROUP_THREAD_COUNT);
            bootstrap.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                    .channel(EpollServerSocketChannel.class);
        } else {
            bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(BOSS_GROUP_THREAD_COUNT);
            workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(WORKER_GROUP_THREAD_COUNT);
            bootstrap.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class);
            log.fatal("bootStrapNettyServer", "Epoll is not available on this host. Failed over to NioEventLoopGroup class");
        }

        log.info("bootStrapNettyServer","Boss group executor thread count and WorkerGroup executor thread count are",
                "bossGroup", BOSS_GROUP_THREAD_COUNT, "workerGroup", WORKER_GROUP_THREAD_COUNT);

        return bootstrap.bind();
    }

And each of the handlers responsible for doing their own job when called through reflection. Each of the Handler classes have very minimal code that it takes less than ~10 msecs to complete.
private List<MessageHandler<Context>> createHandlers() {
        List<MessageHandler<Context>> handlers = new ArrayList<>();
        handlers.add(new InfoHandler<>(RateEstimator.getRateEstimator()));
        handlers.add(new GetConfigHandler<>(config));
        handlers.add(new SetConfigHandler<>(config));
        handlers.add(new ListHandler(config, appName));
        handlers.add(new DiscoverHandler(appName));
        return handlers;
    }

The Initializer class is defined as follows
public class Initializer extends ChannelInitializer<Channel> {
    private final StumpyVerbDispatcher<CdsContext> dispatcher;

    public Initializer(Context context, List<MessageHandler<Context>> handlers) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(context, "context cannot be null");
        Objects.requireNonNull(handlers, "handlers cannot be null");

        this.dispatcher = new VerbDispatcher<>(context, handlers);
    }

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(Channel channel) {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = channel.pipeline();
        pipeline.addLast(new EventDataInjector()); // duplex
        pipeline.addLast(new ConcurrentRequestsTracker()); // inbound
        pipeline.addLast(new IdleStateHandler(0, 0, 5)); // duplex
        pipeline.addLast(new IdleConnectionCloser()); // duplex
        pipeline.addLast(new StumpyMessageDecoder()); // inbound
        pipeline.addLast(new StumpyMessageEncoder()); // outbound
        pipeline.addLast(dispatcher);
    }
}

When I try to send a request from a client which is residing on a different machine this Netty server is not able to handle more than 1k TPS. And the latency for the requests is 5 seconds because the IdleStateHandler is set 5.
I see logs inside the IdleConnectionCloser which is defined as follows
private static final class IdleConnectionCloser extends ChannelDuplexHandler {
        private static final Logger log = new Logger(IdleConnectionCloser.class);

        @Override
        public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) throws Exception {
            EventData eventData = ctx.channel().attr(EventDataInjector.KEY).get();
            if (evt instanceof IdleStateEvent) {
                String peer = ctx.channel().remoteAddress().toString();
                if (eventData != null) {
                    eventData.incCounter("idleConnection", 1);
                    log.warn("IdleConnectionCloser", "Killing idle connection", "peer", peer, "time: ", System.currentTimeMillis(), "requestId", eventData.getValue(REQUEST_ID));
                    eventData.setStatus(FAILED);
                }
                ctx.close();
            } else {
                log.warn("IdleConnectionCloser", "Time in IdleConnectionCloser", "time: ", System.currentTimeMillis(), "requestId", eventData.getValue(REQUEST_ID));
                super.userEventTriggered(ctx, evt);
            }
        }
    }

Can anyone help me understand if there is anything wrong with my setup ?
I tried increasing the Socket Backlog size to 4096 but it didn't help as well.
